# Java: Error when compiling packages on PC

Tags: java, package

I compiled a few java files on my laptop and now I tried opening them on my PC and I just get error messages that the packages dont work.
F.e. here are two files in the folder "webshop":

```
  package webshop;

     public abstract class Article {
        int artCode;
        float price;
        int stock;
        
        public void buy (int n) {
            stock += n;
        }
    
        public void sell (int n) {
            stock -= n;
        }
    
        public boolean available () {
            return stock > 0;
        }
    
        public String getDescription () {
            return "ArtNr. " + artCode + " €" + price;
        }
    
        public Article (int ac, float p) {
            artCode = ac;
            price = p;
            stock = 0;
        }
    }
```

and

```
package webshop;
import webshop.Article;

public abstract class Book extends Article {
    String author;
    String title;

    public String getDescription () {
        return getKind() + " '" + title + "' von " +
            author + "; " + super.getDescription();
    }

    public abstract String getKind ();

    public Book (int ac, float p, String a, String t) {
        super(ac, p);
        author = a;
        title = t;
    }

    public Book (int ac, String a, String t) {  // construct a free book
        super(ac, 0);
        author = a;
        title = t;
    }
}
```

Now when I compile Book.java on my PC , I get the error that no package "webshop" exists, but on my laptop it works completely fine. Any ideas? Both files are in the same folder named webshop.
Greets

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you are running these files?  Is it possible that you are running them from a higher up directory, and therefore it expects a longer package identifier?

Comment: I've got the files in C:\Users\x\Desktop\project\webshop , and I first compile the Article.java then the Book.java. I compile them via the javac command in cmd

Comment: In your pc the package webshop is not available. I assume you completed the code in laptop in any of the ide (eclipse, intellij) and moving the code to pc to build a jar. All good. In pc you have to create a folder webshop and place the files over there. now you have to run javac from the parent folder of webshop folder.

javac ./webshop/Article.java
javac ./webshop/Book.java

If even this does not work, you can just remove the import and package statements in both the files and just compile, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks ntonzz, I ran javac from the parent folder and it worked, I could swear I've tried that, but it works now , thank you a lot!